# using GCC command prompt

Tags: linux, gcc

```html
gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DPRNT -DTYPE=float -DBUBB *.c
```

I have this command line that we need to use in order to compile a program. The command creates a.out file. Now this is for bubble sorting purpose but a.out file generates random numbers but i would like to sort any numbers of my wish. May i know how to use command line to do that ? I am new to linux, do i need to associate any text file with a.out file ? If so how do i do that once a.out file is created ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the code for the file you are compiling.

Comment: Your question is not clear. a.out generates random numbers that you want to use as *input* for some other program that does bubble sort?

Comment: @BlueMoon - when i type ./a.out i wish to sort the numbers that i input myself. For instance if i want to sort integer type say (0,2,1,8,7,4) then how do i do that ? Basically i am asking for what would be the code in command prompt where we can ask user to enter number and then sort those numbers when i do ./a.out

Comment: If a.out reads from user (stdin) then you could do: `echo 0 2 1 8 7 4 | ./a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, your program generates random numbers, sorts them and then prints them out.

If you are interested in sorting, you can use Linux [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) utility. To sort a text file you would do in the console:

```
sort text-file.txt
```

Or:

```
cat text-file.txt | sort
```

If you would like to make your own application sort any text file, change it to read the input from `stdin` and print the sorted output into `stdout`. Then invoke it the same way as `sort` above.